# css doesnt work with html component

Tags: css, jsf

I dont understand why css classes doesnt work.

newcss.css:

```
.greenClass {
    color: green;
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="newcss.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:form styleClass="greenClass">
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="greenClass" value="AAA"/>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

HTML code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WA/faces/javax.faces.resource/newcss.css" /></head>
<form id="j_idt4" name="j_idt4" method="post" action="/WA/faces/index.xhtml" class="greenClass" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt4" value="j_idt4" />
<label class="greenClass">AAA</label><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-7146797988252848648:-7580080555543519594" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
</html>
```

and this doesnt work

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="greenClass" value="AAA"/>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

But the following works correctly:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel style="color: green" value="AAA"/>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

HTML Code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<form id="j_idt2" name="j_idt2" method="post" action="/WA/faces/index.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt2" value="j_idt2" />
<label style="color:green">AAA</label><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="8578298320156968921:4997153480898762925" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
</html>
```

Can you explain what can be reason of this and how to fix this?

Comment: Show us the **generated** HTML when it "doesn't work."

Comment: If you look in your browser's console when it "doesn't work," is it able to fetch the stylesheet file? If so what's in the stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, that doesn't work, you're missing the

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="newcss.css"/>
</h:head>
```

part.